# Are there any open topological spaces other than $\mathbb{R}^3$ with overall zero curvature (and asymptotic to $\mathbb{R}^3$ towards infinity)?

Tags: general-topology, homology-cohomology, curvature

What I mean by this is as follows:

Take an infinite flat manifold $\mathbb{R}^3$ with zero curvature. Then subtract out a knotted torus or linked tori. And sew them back in using Dehn surgery.

(In the 2 dimensional case, the resulting manifold will always have overall negative curvature. i.e. it is just a plane with cross-caps and handles.)

In the 3 dimensional case are there any manifolds made by this procedure that have overall zero or even positive curvature? Do you have any examples? And how would you work this out? Are there any that are "flat" as in zero-curvature at every point?

Another way to put this is are there any topologies which are $\mathbb{R}^3$ outside a certain region but have overall zero curvature? Or if it is impossible does this mean all infinite manifolds which are $\mathbb{R}^3$ outside a certain region and have overall zero curvature are equal to $\mathbb{R}^3$?

(The one I would try first would be similar to the way of getting the Poincare homology sphere by cutting out a trefoil knot in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and sewing it back in with +1 surgery. In fact you would only consider Dehn surgeries that give positively curved manifolds when done on $S^3$. But it doesn't prove that doing the same surgery on $\mathbb{R}^3$ would give a overall flat manifold.)

I suppose a third way of asking the same question is: "Are there any Dehn surgeries which don't alter the curvature of the original manifold".

Comment: Not sure if completely understand your question, but if you take $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus C$ for some closed set $C$, then this is a flat manifold. Another thing to consider is a cylinder (which is flat.) By removing one line you get $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for since these are not equal to R3 (by which I mean an infinite flat 3-manifold)  outside a certain region. I'm looking for things that are R3 except in a certain region where it might have special topological structure like handles or cross-caps and their 3d equivalents. (Think of the 2D example which is just an infinite plane with handles and cross-caps in a small region).

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you're asking whether there exists a complete Euclidean $3$-manifold $M$  not isometric to $\mathbb{R}^3$ and compact sets $K\subset M$ and $K'\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $M-K$ is isometric to $\mathbb{R}^3 - K'$.

Comment: @Jim That sounds right. Although I don't know if "Euclidean" and "zero total curvature" are necessarily equivalent. My intuition says they are but intuition is not always correct in topology! For example can a 3-manifold not have parts that are positively curved and parts that are negatively curved, but which the total curvature is zero. (Does total curvature even make sense in this context? I'm not sure.) The geometrization conjecture, as I understand it, says that you can only assign geometries to parts of the manifold not the whole thing.

Comment: @zooby Well, this brings up the question of what exactly you mean by things like "positive curvature" and "negative curvature".  Unlike the situation for surfaces, where the curvature is described by a single scalar, the curvature of a 3-manifold is a tensor.

Comment: @Jim Hmm. So maybe "total curvature" does't make doesn't make sense for 3-manifolds? (But they say the Poincare homology sphere has positive curvature, so what does that mean?).  But if we restrict it to Euclidean 3-manifolds I guess there's no solution.

Comment: @zooby There is something called [scalar curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_curvature) for a 3-manifold which is a scalar.  Also, the Poincare homology sphere is a spherical 3-manifold, so it's positively curved in every possible sense, e.g. all of the sectional curvatures are positive, the Ricci curvatures are positive, and the scalar curvature is positive.